# Rest api design with relational data

Tags: javascript, database, api, rest, express

So this question is less of a problem I have and more of a question about how I should go about implementing something.

lets imagine for example I have a `User` and a `Resource`, and a `User` can have multiple `Resource` but a `Resource` can have only 1 `User`. How should you go about creating api endpoints for interacting with this data?

should it be something like

```js
// POST /api/users/resource (to create a resource)
```

or something like

```js
// POST /api/resource
```

thats just one example, but there is a lot of questions like that, that come to mind when im thinking about this.
it would be nice if someone who knew what is the right approach (or just a good approach) would give an example on how you would structure api endpoints with relational data like this.

any and all help is appreciated thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would go with the latter one. The reason for doing that would be the endpoint `/api/resource` does not bind us to create resources with respect to the user. Down the line in future, we could create resources for `Supplier` (a hypothetical example). Thus having better flexibility and not needing to change the endpoint for Supplier.

Answer (score 0):

Part of the point of REST is that the server's implementation of a resource is hidden behind the uniform interface.  In a sense, you aren't supposed to be able to tell from the resource identifiers whether or not you are dealing with "relational data".

Which is freeing (because you get to design the best possible resource model for your needs); but also leads to analysis-paralysis, because the lack of constraints means that you have many options to choose from.

---

```
POST /api/users/resource 
POST /api/resource
```

Both of these are *fine*.  The machines are perfectly happy to carry either message.  If you wanted to implement an API that supported both options, that would also be OK.

So how do we choose?

The answer to this really has two parts.  The first relates to understanding [resources](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_2_1_1), which are really just generalizations of documents.  When we ask for a document on the web, one of the things that can happen is that the document can be [cached](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234).  If we are sending a message that we expect to modify a document, then we probably want caches to [invalidated](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-4.4) previously cached versions of the document.

And the primary key used to identified cached documents?  The URI.

In the case where we are sending a message to a server to save a new document, and we expect the server to choose its own identifier for its copy of the new document, then one logical choice of request target is the resource that is *the index of documents on the server*.

This is why you will normally see CreateItem operations implemented as POST handlers on a Collection resource - if the item is successfully added, we want to invalidate previously cached responses to `GET /collection`.

Do you have to do it that way?  No, you do not - it's a "trade off"; you weigh the costs and benefits of the options, and choose one.  If you wanted to instead have a separate resource for the CreateItem operation, that's OK too.

The second part of the answer relates to the URI - having decided which document should be handling the requests, what spelling should we use for the *identifier* of that document.

And, once again, the machines don't care very much.  It needs to be RFC 3986 compliant, and you'll save yourself a *lot* of bother if you choose a spelling that works well with [URI Templates](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6570), but that still leaves you with a lot of freedom.

The usual answer?  Think about the people, who they are, and what they are doing when they are looking at a URI.  You've got visitors looking at a browser history, and writers trying to document the API, and operators reading through access logs trying to understand the underlying traffic patterns.  Pick a spelling that's going to be helpful to the people you care about.